# Simple recursive C++ code keeps crashing

Tags: c++, recursion, iostream

So I'm teaching myself C++ and I'm struggling to understand why this code keeps crashing. I've identified that this line: string str = to_string(n) is probably incorrect. But I'm not seeing the other errors for why it's crashing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void write_vertically(int n)
{
    string str = to_string(n);

    if (str.length()>=0) 
    {
        cout<<stoi(str.substr(0,1))<<endl;
        write_vertically(stoi(str.substr(1,str.length())));
    }

}

int main( ) 
{
    write_vertically(1234567890);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `str.length() >= 0` might be `str.length() > 0` maybe ?

Comment: What do you think `std::to_string(0)` will return ? What the length of it's result will be?

Comment: @Victor I'm not quite sure. It seems to me that it would return nothing because it's undefined.

Comment: @KacheFlowe Not undefined! It returns a string that represents the value of `0`, and that would be as if you constructed a string with `"0"`

Comment: for sure not the cause of the stack overflow, but just to get cleaner semantics, you could set the value of the second parameter of std.substr to either string::npos or str.length()-1

Comment: Probably you don't believe me, but running the code with a debugger can solve a problem very quickly rather than ask us to solve the problem before you try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are having a Stack Overflow! And you're on the perfect website to find a solution to that.

In the line `string str = to_string(n);`
No matter the value of `n`, `to_string` is going to return a non-empty string, which could be "0", "6" or "1653", whatever.

The end condition for your recursion is if `(str.length() >= 0)` is false.
However, as stated above that is never false.

What did you intend the end condition of your recursion to be? Maybe we can help you with that.

Edit: It turns out that the code should crash before going into a stack overflow, because it would end up calling `stoi` with an empty string, which makes it throw an `std::invalid_argument`. However, there was still an infinite recursion problem, so I will keep my answer up.

Comment: Such a cheerful answer! My hope was to return a simple 10 digit number on a new line. Line by line. So for example. If I had a number that was 1234567890 it would return

Comment: It would return each digit on a new line

Comment: "And you're on the perfect website to find a solution to that."
Are you sure?
I find it really hard to search for the term stackoveflow on this site, as one simply drowns in false positives due to the site name.

Comment: @Kaiserludi It was mostly a joke/pun. It's like you'd expect it to be the typical question on this site

Comment: @KacheFlowe Anyway, I think my answer answers your question has to why your code is crashing. If you need to fix your code after that, take a look at the other answer attempts and find one that works for you

Comment: Doesn't this directly imply that stoi returns 0 on failure? I thought that shit was abolished with the dinosaurs..

Comment: @Puppy What should stoi return on an empty string? There's no `NaN` for ints

Comment: Throw an exception? Return an optional<int> instead? Hell, terminate the program. Anything other than "Return a value which is a perfectly reasonable success value and just totally ignore the fact that it failed".

Comment: @Everyone You guys rock.

Comment: @Puppy Throwing an exception can't really apply, because a function from the standard library should have well defined semantics even in environments where exceptions are disabled. std::optional has not been standardized yet, and changing the return value would break code.
Terminate is not desirable for most environments. 
One decent solution I can think of would be to add an optional argument to stoi that would store an error code, if the caller wants to check for errors

Comment: @KABoissonneault The error is caused by `stoi("")`, not a stack overflow

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun Do you have any quote that calling `stoi` with an empty string breaks its contract? I can't find any information on that.

Comment: @KABoissonneault I don't know about that, but that is what is causing the error https://ideone.com/YfYhZw

Comment: @KABoissonneault: There are lots of functions in the stdlib that have undefined semantics if you can't throw exceptions. Exceptions are a core language feature. As for std::optional not being Standard yet, that is purely the fault of the Committee (as is this mess). Terminate is undesirable but superior to this. Your "decent" solution is an abysmal wreck of "Forgot to check out parameter" errors and one of the only solutions that's completely unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `stoi("")` at the end

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void write_vertically(int n){
    string str = to_string(n);
    cout<<stoi(str.substr(0,1))<<endl;
    if (str.length()>1) 
         write_vertically(stoi(str.substr(1,str.length())));

}

int main( ) {
    write_vertically(1234567890);
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/YfYhZw

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a lot of (unnecessary) type conversion. Here's a way to accomplish your goal without using strings.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void write_vertically( unsigned int n ) {
    unsigned int d = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    if( n )
        write_vertically( n );
    cout << d << endl;
}

int main() {
    write_vertically(1234567890);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this print the numbers from end to start, instead of start to end?
And I think this would print an extra 0 if the initial number doesn't end with 0.

Comment: ^Okay now I'm curious. Why does it do that?

Comment: @KacheFlowe Because the function enters into the recursion before printing. The function would keep calling itself until it finds a 0, print the 0 then return and the previous functions would print d after.
Your original code did it properly, though.

Comment: But when I tried compiling it, it seemed to work fine. I ended the number with a non-zero and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: It prints the numbers left to right (most to least significant). It does NOT print the most implicit 0 in the most significant digit. The if condition prevents calling the implicit 0.

Comment: @KABoissonneault You could have tried it : https://ideone.com/YfYhZw, his code is correct and prints everything in the correct order, the recursion goes from right to left but the printing goes from left to right

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun Ah, right, the modulo takes the right most digit first in this code. My mistake

Comment: If you tried to print the number 01234, it would print 1234. As would your original code (after being fixed). This is because the int(eger) form of the two numbers are equivalent.

Comment: ^That's why I was initially confused.

Comment: @KacheFlowe And I agree with putnampp, this solution is better by far.

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun This is certainly the most elegant solution.

Comment: @KacheFlowe this is really only a half 'solution'. It only works for positive integers. If you want to continue learning you may want to consider how to modify the code to work for all integers.

Comment: Fascinating! Then I will try so.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your recursion condition as follows:

```
if (str.length()> 0) {

cout<<stoi(str.substr(0,1))<<endl;
if(str.length() > 1)
write_vertically(stoi(str.substr(1,str.length())));
     }


}
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecd26e57c45cea2b

Comment: the last '0' is missing .